# custom user authentication work fine with python3.5 but doesn't work well with python3.6

Tags: python-3.x, django, authentication

[image: when I click on profile view I get this]
I just download this git project
[here](https://github.com/cdelange/caseygram)
this is a demo of the project
[here](https://caseygram.herokuapp.com/)
after I install requirements.txt work very fine with python3.5 but if I switch to python3.6 or 3.8,
can not see user profile and if try to click on user view profile, its just download the file or show profile.html template script tagged,
I thought python3.5 and python 3.6 should be almost same how come it's not work in python 3.6
already I checked all package which I have in python 3.5 moved to python 3.6
I tried this comment

> pip3.5 list | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -I{} pip3.8 install {}

to move all package and also I tried manually check if I don't have any uninstall package

Comment: I would avoid copying packages across like that. The repo comes with a `requirements.txt` file, so create a Python 3.8 virtual environment, activate it, then run `python -m pip install -r requirements`.

Comment: @Alasdair I just add a screenshot of when I click on header profile view icon I got this screen

Comment: And what does `manage.py runserver` show when the browser is displaying the html code?

Comment: @Alasdair
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
July 30, 2020 - 09:13:48
Django version 3.0.8, using settings 'caseygram.settings'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[30/Jul/2020 09:13:56] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 31521
Not Found: /media/default.jpg
[30/Jul/2020 09:13:56] "GET /media/default.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1791
[30/Jul/2020 09:13:58] "GET /profile/zporta/ HTTP/1.1" 200 27203

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bug in the [`public_profile`](https://github.com/cdelange/caseygram/blob/fb4fbe71a20c15a28a14dc8b0e3e4621d3043fbc/homepage/views.py#L220) view.

```
@login_required
def public_profile(request, username):  # learn how in bookmarks
    obj = User.objects.get(username=username)  # grabs <username> from url and stores it in obj to  be passed into the context
    context = {
        'posts': Post.objects.filter(author__username=obj).order_by('-date_posted'),
        ...
    }
    response = render(request, 'homepage/public_profile.html', context, {'title': 'Public-Profile'})
    return response
```

The fourth argument to [render](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) should be `content_type`, so the dictionary `{'title': 'Public-Profile'}` is not valid. It looks as if that key/value should be part of the `context` dictionary instead:

```
@login_required
def public_profile(request, username):  # learn how in bookmarks
    obj = User.objects.get(username=username)  # grabs <username> from url and stores it in obj to  be passed into the context
    context = {
        'posts': Post.objects.filter(author__username=obj).order_by('-date_posted'),
        ...
        'title': 'Public-Profile',
    }
    response = render(request, 'homepage/public_profile.html', context)
    return response
```

I guess `manage.py runserver` is sending a different `Content-Type` header for different Python versions (you could investigate with `curl -I` or your browser tools). Your browser then displays the raw html when the Content-Type header is not `text/html`.